# How to NOT require sign in every time a file is opened in office desktop from Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

We have a conference room computer that is shared by everyone in the office. Whenever someone opens a powerpoint file in desktop mode, powerpoint asks the user to sign in every time. Then we end up with 2-3 people logged into powerpoint at the same time, when the next person goes to login powerpoint just freezes and we have to sign out all other users, re open the file, sign in and it works fine.

(I just used powerpoint as an example, this happens with all office applications)

I know there is a way for a user to sign into sharepoint and if they have a license that allows for desktop applications. The desktop application will not ask the user to sign in because the credentials are already in sharepoint. I have not figured out how to set this up properly. I would greatly appreciate any tips! Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're probably being prompted because you need to add the site to your trusted sites in your browser.

Comment: Thank you that solved part of my problem. Is there a way to make it so whoever is signed into sharepoint will also be signed into the desktop office program too. When I tested this, I was not asked for a password from the desktop program but I was signed in as the last person who signed into word. I'm talking about the sign in name in the top right corner of word.

Comment: Not sure about the Office question. If you don't want other users to have to sign in to the browser, you'll need to set up a group policy that pushes the settings I mentioned to everyone when they sign into their PC.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, set ‘Automatic logon with current user name and password in Local intranet zone and Trusted sites of IE.

Navigate to IE->Internet options->Security tab->Local intranet and Trusted sites->Custom level->choose automatic logon with current user name and password:

[image]